# Is there a reference for MongoDB's map reduce javascript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql

I've got some dates in my documents and trying to manipulate them. I was expecting the JavaScript to support standard date methods such as the `toISOString()`, but to my surprise I get an error `Database command 'mapreduce' failed: (assertion: 'invoke failed: JS Error: TypeError: entry.start.toISOString is not a function nofile_b:0'; assertionCode: '9004'; errmsg: 'db assertion failure'; ok: '0.0').`

How can I find out what is supported by the Map Reduce runtime environment?

Comment: Are you sure that `entry.start` is a Date?

Comment: @muistooshort yes there is. I can call `entry.start.toUTCString()` but not `entry.start.toISOString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the easiest way to debug map reduce is to break down the components and use the console.

Unfortunately, it seems in the embedded spidermonkey engine there is no toISOString

```
> d = new Date()
> d.to<tab-complete>
  d.toDateString(        d.toLocaleString(      d.toTimeString(
  d.toGMTString(         d.toLocaleTimeString(  d.toUTCString(
  d.toLocaleDateString(  d.toString(            d.tojson(
```

So you'd have to generate your own, I cheated by using to json and using substr:

```
> d.tojson().substr(9, 24)
  2012-07-26T09:42:11.403Z
```